# How to total SQL results

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

How do I get my results to total into one record instead of multiple instances of  item_id. instead I need the total qty invoiced for each item.

Query Results
https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJkXl.jpg

```
select
inv_mast.default_product_group,
inv_mast.item_id,
inv_mast.item_desc,oe_hdr.order_date,
oe_line.qty_invoiced,
oe_line.extended_price 

from
job_price_hdr

join oe_hdr on oe_hdr.job_price_hdr_uid = job_price_hdr.job_price_hdr_uid 
join oe_line on oe_line.order_no = oe_hdr.order_no
join inv_mast on inv_mast.inv_mast_uid = oe_line.inv_mast_uid

where
oe_line.qty_invoiced> 0
and
oe_hdr.customer_id = 100080
and
default_product_group = 'FAST'

order by
inv_mast.item_id
```

Comment: sql has a sum() function.  Do you know how to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this and let me know if you need more information

```
 select
    inv_mast.item_id,SUM(oe_line.qty_invoiced)
    from
    job_price_hdr

    join oe_hdr on oe_hdr.job_price_hdr_uid = job_price_hdr.job_price_hdr_uid 
    join oe_line on oe_line.order_no = oe_hdr.order_no
    join inv_mast on inv_mast.inv_mast_uid = oe_line.inv_mast_uid

    where
    oe_line.qty_invoiced> 0
    and
    oe_hdr.customer_id = 100080
    and
    default_product_group = 'FAST'
    GROUP BY inv_mast.item_id
    order by
    inv_mast.item_id
```

Comment: When I add my columns back into the select portion, it errors because these columns in the select list aren't in an Agg Function or the group by clause. When I add them to the group by it returns each record again but this time with a total amount